# How could i display the items from 3 tables joined

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How could i display the items from 3 tables below joining using the product_tbl id.

and using foreach. or if there is any alternative way to display it.

[The tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L5MT.png)

I couldn't get the 3rd table or pictures table. 
using my existing code below.
still error.

```
$product_list = DB::table('product_tbl')

        ->leftjoin('brand_tbl', 'product_tbl.id', '=', 'brand_tbl.product_id')

        ->select('*')

        ->get();

return vehicles_list;


    $prod_list = array();
    foreach ($product_list as $key => $value) {

        $prod_list [$value->products_name][] = $value;

    }

print_r($prod_list);
```

please help me thank you.

Comment: It will be better if you try to use Eloquent Relationships. These things will become a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If your table structure isn't set in stone you might try the following structure for a more normalized and indexable structure.  I made some changes - changing product to category, and brand to product.  These labels made more sense to me as I worked with this. I also do full namespaced field names to make joining possible without aliasing all field names.

[image: Visual Representation of a proposed table structure]

*see the bottom of this post for the SQL to generate and populate these tables*

Then a different query will definitely help.  You're not joining on the picture table in your code.

```sql
select * from so_category
left outer join so_product on ( product_category_id = category_id)
left outer join so_picture on ( picture_category_id = category_id )
```

But this will probably not return your data like you want to consume it.

[image: Full Query Result]

In which case the [Mysql Group Concat Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html) might help.

```sql
SELET
so_category.*,
so_product.*,
(select GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT picture_url order by picture_url asc separator "," )) AS images
FROM so_category
LEFT OUTER JOIN so_product ON ( product_category_id = category_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN so_picture ON ( picture_category_id = category_id )
GROUP BY product_id
```

Which yields results that do not duplicate data.
[image: Group Concat Query Result]

## SQL to create and populate tables.

```sql
-- Create syntax for TABLE 'so_category'
CREATE TABLE `so_category` (
  `category_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'so_picture'
CREATE TABLE `so_picture` (
  `picture_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `picture_url` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `picture_category_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`picture_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'so_product'
CREATE TABLE `so_product` (
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_brand_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_category_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `so_category` (`category_id`, `category_name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'chocolate'),
    (2, 'flower');

INSERT INTO `so_picture` (`picture_id`, `picture_url`, `picture_category_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'dmc1', 1),
    (2, 'dmc2', 1),
    (3, 'dmc3', 2),
    (4, 'dmc4', 2),
    (5, 'dmc5', 2);

INSERT INTO `so_product` (`product_id`, `product_name`, `product_brand_id`, `product_category_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'hershey', NULL, 1),
    (2, 'tobleron', NULL, 1),
    (3, 'oreo', NULL, 1),
    (4, 'roses', NULL, 2),
    (5, 'sunflower', NULL, 2);
```